Checking the correctness of the connection of the STM32L010F4P6
Here is such a scheme, I added the selection of BOOT0 via a jumper, put a resistor on this pin according to the datasheet, I did not put an external oscillator 32.768 kHz on the pins PC14 and PC15 because I considered it unnecessary for my tasks (I will not use a real-time clock and the PWM will be a maximum of 3-5 kHz), the LED and PWM labels will be for creating a PWM (flashlight and adjusting the brightness of the display), UP, AVER and DOWN will be used to read the state of the buttons (their connection is below), the PWR_BT and PWR_EN labels will be for creating a high signal and reading the button (in the diagram below), I would like to check whether everything is connected correctly and whether I missed anything since I am working with STM32 for the first time.






How much voltage is on BF+ node and can the unpowered or powered MCU handle it without damage?

I have 4.2-2.8V, this is the on/off circuit for the power supply of my entire device. In principle, the voltage does not greatly exceed the nominal voltage for the STM32, but from this part the voltage will not go to the pin where the STM32 is, so in theory it can.

How do you plan load firmware (or debug) MCU ... ?

@Pisppus It must not exceed allowable range in all conditions. If it is a 3.3V tolerant pin, it must not exceed the MCU supply and MCU supply might br 0V.

@Justme What should I do then to ensure it doesn't exceed? I saw an example of such a circuit for ESP32 and everything worked fine there, it is also designed for 3.3V

@Michal Dudka I plan to flash via SWD, it won’t work via UART because I want to use it to transmit commands (communicate) to the ESP32 as with the main microcontroller.

@Pisppus Circuits may be designed by hobbyists who don't understand how to use chips reliably and avoid short-term and long-term damage. At least what you could do is to not send 4.2V directly to an IO pin of unpowered chip which is definitely beyond limit. It must be VDD+4.0V so when MCU is unpowered maximum is 4V. Best to always between 0V and VDD. Perhaps use a transistor to either pull the pin low or let it float.

@Pisppus Then you should wire out SWD pins and move UP and AVER signals to another GPIOs.

It's technically almost correct.
But you must not let the pushbutton to send more than 4V to MCU pin, it's a 5V tolerant pin but it does not tolerate more than 4.0V when unpowered MCU VDD is 0V. For a non-5V tolerant pin with protection diodes built-in, a series resistor would do, but not in this case as the 5V tolerant pins don't have the protection diodes so that they can tolerate 5V.
Also the pull-up resistors on buttons may be redundant as the MCU has internal pull-ups you can enable. They are in the order of 25 to 65 kohm, so the 10k resistor is not much better than the internal pull-ups.
The capacitors over pushbuttons may also have a negative effect on the circuit. When the button is pushed, it will discharge the capacitor with a short circuit, causing large current spike through the pushbutton. The button may not be rated for it, and the current pulse of bouncy contacts may cause other adverse effects in the inductance of PCB wiring. So in short, making pushbuttons discharge caps by short-circuiting rarely makes sense. At least you could exchange the pull resistors to series resistors to keep discharge current below rated current of the pushbutton.
Now for the rest of the circuit, the LED and PWM pin usage is unknown.

I used capacitors and resistors for the buttons as signal smoothing to avoid false triggering, the capacitors are not of high capacity so I think everything should be fine
As for that pin, if you use a pin that does not support 5v, do you need to put a series resistor or what? I can also change the pin that will control this, choosing the one that will be more convenient to connect to the board.

I added circuits to control the display and flashlight.

@Pisppus Shorting out caps with pushbuttons is not very "smooth" and there's better way like I explained. And yes you could change to 3V only pin if you use a series resistor, but it is a poor solution instead of doing it better with a transistor like I explained. Are you sure you want to drive the LEDs from regulated 3.3V supply instead of battery? That's a good amount of current pulses and if your regulator cannot handle it the voltage will drop and the MCU will reset.

Each LED takes 60mA which is not much, as a regulator I use TPS63020 the current in the whole circuit should be less than 1A for sure.
